# Spring fails when java splits classes

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I've created spring security configuration class with two configuration subclasses for frontend & backend.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    private static AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new FakeAuthenticationProvider();

    /**
     * Frontend security configuration
     */
    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class FrontendSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .hasRole("USER")
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage( "/login")
                    .permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true);

        }
    }

    /**
     * Backend security configuration
     */
    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class BackendSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Autowired
        private String backendUrl;

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.antMatcher(backendUrl + "**").authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage(backendUrl + "login")
                    .permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl(backendUrl, true);
        }
    }

}
```

And Java compiles three class files for it:
`SecurityConfig$FrontendSecurityConfiguration.class
SecurityConfig$BackendSecurityConfiguration.class
SecurityConfig.class`

```
15-May-2015 13:38:21.971 WARNING [http-nio-8082-exec-68] org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.refresh Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.aplhost.panel.core.config.AppConfig]; nested exception is org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'securityConfig.BackendSecurityConfiguration' for bean class [com.aplhost.panel.core.config.SecurityConfig$BackendSecurityConfiguration] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [com.aplhost.panel.core.SecurityConfig$BackendSecurityConfiguration]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:179)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:306)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:239)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1293)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:673)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:221)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:213)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'securityConfig.BackendSecurityConfiguration' for bean class [com.aplhost.panel.core.config.SecurityConfig$BackendSecurityConfiguration] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [com.aplhost.panel.core.SecurityConfig$BackendSecurityConfiguration]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.checkCandidate(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:320)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:259)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:140)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:265)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:229)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:196)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:165)
        ... 44 more

15-May-2015 13:38:21.973 SEVERE [http-nio-8082-exec-68] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Context initialization failed
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.aplhost.panel.core.config.AppConfig]; nested exception is org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'securityConfig.BackendSecurityConfiguration' for bean class [com.aplhost.panel.core.config.SecurityConfig$BackendSecurityConfiguration] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [com.aplhost.panel.core.SecurityConfig$BackendSecurityConfiguration]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:179)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:306)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:239)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1293)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:673)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:221)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:213)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'securityConfig.BackendSecurityConfiguration' for bean class [com.aplhost.panel.core.config.SecurityConfig$BackendSecurityConfiguration] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [com.aplhost.panel.core.SecurityConfig$BackendSecurityConfiguration]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.checkCandidate(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:320)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:259)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:140)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:265)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:229)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:196)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:165)
        ... 44 more

15-May-2015 13:38:21.974 SEVERE [http-nio-8082-exec-68] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
```

But eclipse compiles just one file SecurityConfig.class and everythng works correctly.

Does anybody know how to fix it?

Comment: Eclipse also creates those files as that is how internal classes are represented.

Comment: Not for me. My eclipse creates just one file instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I have resolved this issue. Just added `@Configuration` annotation for the top class `SecurityConfig`.